# View only updates on Model OnPropertyChanged but not in ViewModel OnPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a ViewModel hosting properties of Model classes, where both the ViewModel and the Model implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

However, the View only updates if the properties in the Model are changed. If a property is changed in the ViewModel, the View is not updated.

Model base:

```
public class BaseModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int id;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Id")); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs propertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyChangedEventArgs.PropertyName));
    }
}
```

Model (Adding and Removing to the Positionen-Collection are shown in the View):

```
public class ChildModel : BaseModel 
{

    private ObservableCollection<SubModel> positionen;

    public ObservableCollection<SubModel> Positionen
    {
        get { return positionen; }
        set { positionen = value; OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Positionen")); }
    }
}
```

ViewModel base:

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel<T> where T : BaseModel , INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    protected void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs propertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, propertyChangedEventArgs);
    }


    public abstract ObservableCollection<T> DatensatzListe { get; set; }

    public abstract T AktuellerDatensatz { get; set; }

}
```

ViewModel child (updates to the properties here are not shown in the View):

```
public class ChildViewModel : BaseViewModel<ChildModel >
{
    public override ObservableCollection<ChildModel > DatensatzListe
    {
        get { return DatensatzListe; }
        set { DatensatzListe = value; }
    }

    private ChildModel aktuellerDatensatz;

    public override ChildModel AktuellerDatensatz
    {
        get { return aktuellerDatensatz; }
        set { aktuellerDatensatz = value; OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("AktuellerDatensatz")); }
    }

    private string tesxt;

    public string Tesxt
    {
        get { return tesxt; }
        set { tesxt = value; OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Tesxt")); }
    }
}
```

If I update the Tesxt Property in the Code behind, updates are not shown in the View. I update AktuellerDatensatz.Id, the change shows up just fine.

How can I fix this. Please let me know, if more code is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the following definition,

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel<T> where T : BaseModel , INotifyPropertyChanged
```

`BaseViewModel` is not derived from `INotifyPropertyChanged` so the view is unaware of its changes.

In the above code the `INotifyPropertyChanged` is a constraint on `T` where `T` must be derived from `BaseModel` and `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Update to

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel<T>: INotifyPropertyChanged 
    where T : BaseModel
```

as `BaseModel` is already derived from `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: Brilliant, Thank you very much!